# "TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly" when var should have a value

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
def print():
    print("Encoded " + message + " with " + offset)

gui = Tk()

gui.title("Caesar Cypher Encoder")

Button(gui, text="Encode", command=encode).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
Label(gui, text = "Message").grid(row = 1, column =0)
Label(gui, text = "Offset").grid(row = 1, column =1)
message = Entry(gui).grid(row=2, column=0)
offset = Scale(gui, from_=0, to=25).grid(row=2, column=1)

mainloop( )
```

When i run this code with an input in both the input box and a value on the slider - it comes up with the error

```
>>>Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Code/Functionised/GUI.pyw", line 5, in encode
print("Encoded " + message + " with " + offset)
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

using a simple str() does not work by the way

EDIT

With the new code

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
def printer():
    print(message)
    print(offset)

gui = Tk()

gui.title("Caesar Cypher Encoder")

Button(gui, text="Encode", command=printer).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
Label(gui, text = "Message").grid(row = 1, column =0)
Label(gui, text = "Offset").grid(row = 1, column =1)
message = Entry(gui)
message.grid(row=2, column=0)
offset = Scale(gui, from_=0, to=25)
offset.grid(row=2, column=1)

mainloop( )
```

It returns

```
.46329264
.46329296
```

EDIT 2

```
def printer():
    print(message.get())
    print(offset.get())
```

this fixes the .xxxxxxxx problem

Comment: If the argument to the inner print call did not raise, you would have an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: That is assuming that you add a dummy argument to avoid calling with too many arguments.  Do change the name of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your first edit - the `.get()` command should be the most useful

Use it in the form of

```
print(message.get())
```

rather than

```
print(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the variables `message` and `offset` to widgets but then you position them on the same line, this makes them `Nonetype` objects, instead position them on the next line e.g.:

```
message = Entry(gui)
message.grid(row=2, column=0)
offset = Scale(gui, from_=0, to=25)
offset.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

this should solve your problem, but also, it's not advised to use `from tkinter import *` rather `import tkinter as tk`, and your function `print()` should be differently named (not the same as a python keyword) so that it is less confusing and prevents errors, make it `printer()` or similar to be on the safe side.

Hope this helps you!