# Tkinter variable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
def printer():
    print(message)
    print(offset)

gui = Tk()

gui.title("Caesar Cypher Encoder")

Button(gui, text="Encode", command=printer).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
Label(gui, text = "Message").grid(row = 1, column =0)
Label(gui, text = "Offset").grid(row = 1, column =1)
message = Entry(gui)
message.grid(row=2, column=0)
offset = Scale(gui, from_=0, to=25)
offset.grid(row=2, column=1)

mainloop( )
```

When i run the above code with an input in both the input box and a value on the slider - it comes up with the ouput

```
.46329264
.46329296
```

How would i get it to display the string inputted into the text box, and the value selected on the slider

Comment: Let me guess, controlled assessment?

Comment: @AlexThornton Originally Yes but as i have finished it i have decided to use the pre existing code to expand and develop upon, i am now in the process of trying to learn TKinter and i think this is a good way to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of ["TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly" when var should have a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822410/typeerror-cant-convert-nonetype-object-to-str-implicitly-when-var-should-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Entry.get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method), [`Scale.get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm#Tkinter.Scale.get-method) methods:

```
def printer():
    print(message.get())
    print(offset.get())
```